# MySQL запрос из четырех таблиц

Tags: mysql, sql

Ребят помогите решить задачку, никак не складываеться в голове..
1) Напишите запрос, который выводит имена всех учеников, сдавших экзамен по математике у профессора Иванова на оценку 4 или 5. 2) Напишите запрос, выводящий имена учеников, пропустивших экзамен по математике у профессора Иванова.
[image: Таблицы]

Comment: Может утром ещё раз поробуете решить самостоятельно.

Comment: Для решения данной задачи, Вам всего лишь понадобится один оператор `JOIN` . Почитайте как он работает, составьте связи - это не сложно, учитывая, что на рисунке они обозначены линиями; и приложите Ваш вариант ответа и если Вам что-то будет не ясно, мы поможем Вам это прояснить.

Comment: Вопрос в данный момент не описывает конкретной проблемы с которой столкнулся автор из-за чего не может выполнить задание, следовательно вопрос должен быть закрыт или переформулирован.

Comment: Почитайте про [`join`](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html), потренируйтесь. У вас простые запросы вида `select ... from ... join ... on ... = ... where ....`, попробуйте самостоятельно изучить или поискать здесь - таких вопросов куча.

Comment: Ребят подскажите хоть правильно ли я сделал?
SELECT name FROM `t_students`
JOIN t_teachers ON WHERE  t_teachers.name         = "Иванов"
JOIN t_exams    ON WHERE  t_exams.exam_name = "Математика"
JOIN t_marks     ON WHERE  t_marks .mark             =  4 AND 5